# Discrepency between curl results and Python requests results

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, newrelic

I am querying the New Relic API, and trying to pull CPU utilization fron the metrics that they provide.  When I run the following curl command (after exporting the correct proxy settings), I see the following information (which contains the percentage value that I want) -

```
 curl -X GET "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/140456413/hosts/21044947/metrics/data.json" -H "X-Api-Key:myapikey" -i -d 'names[]=CPU/User+Time&values[]=percent&summarize=true&from=2018-07-15 16:22:30&to=2018-07-16 16:22:30'
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
Proxy-agent: Apache
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty
Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 11:53:22 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 290
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "a35b451e27a49d0d5f4e16715429a17d"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: f4f8675f095aba80d5e089fbcbf1b172
X-Runtime: 0.168283
X-Rack-Cache: miss

{"metric_data":{"from":"2018-07-15T16:22:30+00:00","to":"2018-07-16T16:22:30+00:00","metrics_not_found":[],"metrics_found":["CPU/User Time"],"metrics":[{"name":"CPU/User Time","timeslices":[{"from":"2018-07-15T16:22:00+00:00","to":"2018-07-16T16:22:00+00:00","values":{"percent":9.52}}]}]}}
```

However, when I try to implement it inside of the Python requests module, the "Percent" value that I am interested in seeing is returning 0.  This is my code to call it -

```
options = {"names[]": "CPU/User+Time", "values[]": "percent", "summarize": "true", "from": str(end_date), "to": str(start_date - datetime.timedelta(hours=6))}
path = "applications/140456413/hosts/" + server_id + "/metrics/data.json"
api_key = "myapikey"

headers = {'X-Api-Key': api_key}
url = "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/" + path
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=options, proxies=myproxy.proxies)
```

This is what I get instead (notice the percent value is now 0) -

```
{u'metric_data': {u'metrics': [{u'timeslices': [{u'values': {u'percent': 0}, u'to': u'2018-07-17T01:35:00+00:00', u'from': u'2018-07-16T07:35:00+00:00'}], u'name': u'CPU/User+Time'}], u'to': u'2018-07-17T01:35:59+00:00', u'metrics_found': [u'CPU/User+Time'], u'from': u'2018-07-16T07:35:59+00:00', u'metrics_not_found': []}}
```

How can I adjust the python request to match the same output as the curl command?  We were originally passing in options inside of the "options" variable using ='s instead of key/value pairs, but the requests module would not process them in this format.

These were the docs pages I referencesd -

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/rest-api-v2/requirements/specifying-time-range-v2
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/rest-api-v2/application-examples-v2/get-average-cpu-usage-host-app
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/rest-api-v2/getting-started/introduction-new-relic-rest-api-v2#examples

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the options a bit:

```
"values[]": "percent"
```

to:

```
"values": ["percent"]
```

Comment: Appreciate it.  Thanks!